# Showing an equivalence of $|\langle \textbf{z}, x \rangle| < R$

Tags: probability, vectors, random-variables

Let us consider the following event: for a fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\|x\|=1$ and $\textbf{z} \sim N(0,\textbf{I}_n)$,
$$
A_x(\textbf{z}) = \{\exists w \in \mathbb{R}^n \text{ such that } \|w - \textbf{z}\| \le R, \text{ and } \text{sign}(\langle w, x\rangle) \ne \text{sign}(\langle \textbf{z}, x\rangle) \}.
$$
I am trying to show that 
$$
A_x(\textbf{z}) \text{ happens } \iff  |\langle \textbf{z}, x\rangle| < R.
$$

($\implies$) This direction is readily done as follow. 
Suppose $A_x(\textbf{z})$ happens. Then there exists $w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\|w - \textbf{z}\| \le R$ and  $\text{sign}(\langle w, x\rangle) \ne \text{sign}(\langle \textbf{z}, x\rangle)$.
Therefore,
$$
R \ge \|w - \textbf{z}\| \ge |\langle (w - \textbf{z}), x\rangle | \ge |\langle  \textbf{z}, x\rangle | 
$$
where the third inequality uses $\text{sign}(\langle w, x\rangle) \ne \text{sign}(\langle \textbf{z}, x\rangle)$.

However, I am not sure why the reverse direction is true.
Here is my attempt.

($\impliedby$) Suppose $R\ge |\langle  \textbf{z}, x\rangle |$.
Then our goal is to find $w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying 
(i) $\|w - \textbf{z}\| \le R$ and (ii) $\text{sign}(\langle w, x\rangle) \ne \text{sign}(\langle \textbf{z}, x\rangle)$.
I was trying to construct $w$ by setting $w = -a\textbf{z}$ for some positive constant $a$. By doing so, the condition (ii) is automatically satisfied. And I was hoping that (i) can be satisfied by carefully choosing $a$.
However, this only works under the condition of $\|\textbf{z}\| \le R$, not 
$|\langle  \textbf{z}, x\rangle | \le R$. This is becuase, by setting $w = -a\textbf{z}$, we have
$$
\|w - \textbf{z}\| = (1+a)\|\textbf{z}\|.
$$
In order for this to be less or equal to $R$, 
$$
a + 1 \le \frac{R}{\|\textbf{z}\|} \iff a \le \frac{R-\|\textbf{z}\|}{\|\textbf{z}\|}.
$$
Since $a$ is positive, we need $\|\textbf{z}\| < R$.

Any suggestions/answers/comments will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply let $w=z-R\cdot \text{sign}(\langle z,x\rangle)x$. Then we have that $\|w-z\|=R\|x\|=R$ and
$$
\langle w,x\rangle=\langle z,x\rangle-R\cdot\text{sign}(\langle z,x\rangle).
$$ We can see that $$
\langle w,x\rangle\langle z,x\rangle=|\langle z,x\rangle|^2-R\cdot |\langle z,x\rangle|\le 0
$$ so $\langle w,x\rangle$ and $\langle z,x\rangle$ cannot be both positive or negative.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That totally makes sense!

Comment: If possible, could you take a look this problem as well? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3128430/matrix-norm-of-a-b-and-their-smallest-eigenvalues/3129211?noredirect=1#comment6446732_3129211

Comment: I've answered it. Please see it.