# Bound the minimum eigenvalue of a symmetric matrix via matrix norms

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-norms

I'm reading a paper in which the authors prove an inequality of the following form:

$$\lVert H-H'\rVert_2 \leq \lVert H-H'\rVert_F \leq \epsilon \tag 1$$

Here $H$ and $H'$ are symmetric real matrices ($H'$ has all positive eigenvalues, if that matters), and the norms are the $L_2$ matrix norm and the Frobenius norm, respectively. With no justification the authors then claim:

$$\lambda_\text{min}(H) \geq \lambda_\text{min}(H') - \epsilon \tag 2$$

where $\lambda_\text{min}$ is the minimum eigenvalue of a matrix.

I can't see how to justify this, or even if (2) is even intended to be deduced from the (1). [Here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.02054.pdf) is the paper - the end of the proof of Lemma 3.2, page 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based on [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3128430/matrix-norm-of-a-b-and-their-smallest-eigenvalues). Below we will be working with some arbitrary inner product, and when we take the norm of a matrix, this means the [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Matrix_norms_induced_by_vector_norms) associated with the vector norm we're using. We have:

**Theorem.** If $A$ and $B$ are real symmetric, then:

$$\lambda_\text{min} (A) \geq \lambda_\text{min} (B) - \lVert A-B\rVert$$
$$\lambda_\text{max} (A) \leq \lambda_\text{max} (B) + \lVert A-B\rVert$$

To prove this, the key is the expression $x^T Mx$, where $M$ is a symmetric matrix and $x$ has unit norm. We need two lemmas about this expression.

> **Lemma 1.** For *any* matrix $M$ and any unit norm $x$:
> $$-\lVert M\rVert \leq x^T Mx\leq \lVert M\rVert$$
> **Proof.** Simple application of Cauchy-Schwartz and of the definition of an operator norm:
> $$|x^TMx|\leq\lVert x\rVert \lVert Mx\rVert\leq \lVert x\rVert^2 \lVert M\rVert=\lVert M\rVert$$

> **Lemma 2.** For any *symmetric* matrix $M$ and any unit norm $x$:
> $$\lambda_\text{min}(M) \leq x^T M x \leq \lambda_\text{max}(M)$$
> and the bounds are attained as $x$ varies over the unit sphere.
>
> **Proof.** Let $M=P^TDP$ where $P$ is orthogonal and $D$ is diagonal. Then
> $$x^TMx = (Px)^TD(Px)$$
> As $x$ varies over the unit sphere, $Px$ varies also over the entire unit sphere, therefore the range of the latter expression above is simply the range of $y^TDy$ as $y$ ranges over the unit sphere. By the [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality) and some other simple arguments, the minimum is attained when $y$ is an eigenvector associated with $\lambda_\text{min}(M)$ and the maximum when $y$ is an eigenvector associated with  $\lambda_\text{max}(M)$.

Finally we can prove the theorem. For any unit norm $x$, we have

$$x^TAx = x^TBx + x^T(A-B)x$$

By applying Lemma 1 to the second term and Lemma 2 to the first term, the minimum of the left hand side is at least $\lambda_\text{min} (B)-\lVert A-B\rVert$. By Lemma 2, we know that the minimum of the left hand side is equal to $\lambda_\text{min} (A)$. A similar argument shows the other inequality in the theorem.